# Как подключиться к Mysql на хостинге phpStorm

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, хостинг

Был у меня свой сервер в другом здании с выделенным ip и доменом. Там заправлял всем OpenServer. К нему легко подключался удаленно по фтп и к бд в PHPStorm. Перес всё на удаленный сервер на reg.ru. Фтп без проблем подключился. C mysql сложности. В PHPstorm выкидывает ошибку при подключении: **[08S01] Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)**.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сапорт особо не помог. Дали попробовать инструкцию по SSH. У меня и с ней ошибка. На что они ответили SSH у них запрещено... и "В качестве решения вы можете попробовать донастроить PHPStorm и подключиться просто через удалённое соединение к MySQL."
Удаленный доступ включен в настройках бд у пользователя. Если у кого-то будет желание самому потыкать на своей иде то могу дать данные для подключения. Бд временный пока не смогу все настроить. Все данные точно корректны тк сапорт написал что есть коннект при использовании моих данных и я сам проверил подключение через отдельно скаченного клиента mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Поменял драйвер JDBC с mysql на amazon aurora mysql. Странно конечно но это сработало.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]